# Adding roles to people in discord using python externally

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a script that lets you control a discord bot externally using a cmd window, I already have some things done but I cant seem to find any examples on how to add roles to people. Here's what I did to create roles

```
elif option == "4":
            guild = await bot.fetch_guild(guildid)
            amount = int(input("[!] Number of roles to make?\n[>] "))
            name = input("[!] Name of roles to make? Type RANDOM for random character names!\n[>] ")
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('[!] Creating Roles [!]'))
            random = name.upper()
            colorcount = "red"
            for i in range (amount):   
                if random == "RANDOM":
                    name =  "".join(choice(characters) for x in range(randint(4, 15)))
                if colorcount == "red":
                    await guild.create_role(name=name,color=discord.Color.red())
                    colorcount = "red"
                elif colorcount == "red":
                    await guild.create_role(name=name,color=discord.Color.red())
                    colorcount = "red"
                currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
                hour = str(currentDT.hour)
                minute = str(currentDT.minute)
                second = str(currentDT.second)
                print(f"{Fore.RED}[{Fore.WHITE}{hour}:{minute}:{second}{Fore.RED}]{Fore.WHITE} Role Created{Fore.RED} :{Fore.WHITE} {name}")
                os.system(f"title Spam creating roles - [{i+1}]")
            input(f"{Fore.RED}[  {Fore.WHITE}  +  {Fore.RED} ] {Fore.WHITE}Created All Roles {Fore.RED}:{Fore.WHITE} [{i+1}] \n[>] ")
            await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('Idle...'))
```

now I want to be able to see the roles and add them to the users but I don't have any idea on how to do that, can anyone give me some ideas? or even better some guide on how to control/code bots externally?

Answer (score 0):

To create roles,

For the rewrite branch:

```
guild = ctx.guild
await guild.create_role(name="role name")
to add color, just add colour=discord.Colour(0xffffff) as an option in create_role, and replace ffffff with the hex code for the color. To add permissions to the role, include permissions=discord.Permissions(permissions=<permission value>)
```

For the async branch:

```
author = ctx.message.author
await client.create_role(author.server, name="role name")
```

to add color (and probably permissions), just do the same as you would for the rewrite branch.

Now, if you want to add roles to a user,

For the rewrite branch:

```
role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="role to add name")
user = ctx.message.author
await user.add_roles(role)
```

For the async branch:

```
user = ctx.message.author
role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="role to add name")
await client.add_roles(user, role)
```

To see which branch you have, do print(discord._version). If it says 1.0.0a, you have the rewrite branch. If it says 0.16.2 or a lower number, you have the async branch. To calculate permission values, you can use this website

note: Discord.py is currently at 1.6

This can be it, try. And it is easy to find on the internet